# How to send GET/POST requests without header and agent information

Tags: http, ddos, denial-of-service

I want to test our DOS prevention system against http requests that are not have header and agent information. Is there any tool I can do that. I tried siege with this command

```
siege -c 3 -b -H "Host: " -A ""  http://10.0.1.2/
```

This command sends requests with empty host and agent values. What I want is to send requests without defining host and agent values.

Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the easiest way of doing this, with `curl` :

```
curl -H "User-Agent:" -H "Host:" http://10.0.1.2/
```

The `-H` argument can be used to set custom headers or to remove them by setting no value on them.

Example of what that command does on my site, with `-v` added for verbosity :

```
andre@network ~ % curl -H "User-Agent:" -H "Host:" http://andredaniel.me -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://andredaniel.me/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fe89:63c8...
* connect to 2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fe89:63c8 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 85.159.208.85...
* Connected to andredaniel.me (85.159.208.85) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Mon, 29 Dec 2014 13:09:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 172
< Connection: close
<
[page contents truncated]
```

As you can see, both the host and user-agent headers are missing and the web server doesn't like that very much because I use virtual hosts and the host header is essential in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Worst case, you could use [netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=nc).

nc example.com 80 << http_message_file

where `example.com` is the host to which you want to connect, `80` is the port to which you want to connect (I chose 80 since that's typical HTTP server port) and `http_message_file` contains the exact HTTP request you want to send, such as

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Comment: Nice answer. Don't forget to put "\r\n\r\n" at the end of header ;)

Comment: @atk Thanks you've helped me answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350838/how-to-send-request-with-null-user-agent nc example.com 80 << http_message_file Did not load the request in the file, rather let me type it using a here DOC. cat http_message_file | nc example.com 80 Did the trick

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will work for you, but why not. 
You can easely use python to send requests as you whish like so:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

From python doc : http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#headers

Try doing the same thing but with empty user_agent and Headers, it worked in my smal test.

Here is the snippet I tested:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = ''
values = ''
headers = { '' : '' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```